# react.js can't import component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, es6-modules

i'm trying to export a component using `export default project;` and importing using

`import project, {toggleCattegories} from './project';`

i get the following warning:

```
./src/components/projecten.js
  Line 2:8:  'project' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

project.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardActions, Button, CardText } from 'react-mdl';

class project extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { activeTab: 0 };
}

        toggleCategories() {
    if (this.state.activeTab === 0) {
        return (
            <div className="projects-grid">
                {/*Web*/}
                <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                    <CardTitle style={{ color: '#000', height: '176px', background: 'url(https://miro.medium.com/max/3600/1*HSisLuifMO6KbLfPOKtLow.jpeg) center / cover' }}></CardTitle>

                    <CardText><h4>Mijn Portfolio</h4>
                        <p>Mijn Portfolio heb ik in ReactJs geschreven. Bekijk het project op github via de button onder deze tekst.</p></CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                        <Button colored style={{ width: "100%" }}><a href="https://github.com/aminaloui/myportfolio">Github</a></Button>
                    </CardActions>

                </Card>

                <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                    <CardTitle style={{ color: '#000', height: '176px', background: 'url(https://miro.medium.com/max/3600/1*HSisLuifMO6KbLfPOKtLow.jpeg) center / cover' }}> </CardTitle>
                    <CardText><h4>Boodschappenlijst</h4>
                        <p>In de applicatie meld je je via je google account aan en kun je een boodschappenlijstje opzetten. De objecten worden opgeslagen in een firebase database. </p></CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                    <Button colored style={{ width: "100%" }}><a href="https://github.com/aminaloui/boodschappen-lijst">Github</a></Button>
                    </CardActions>

                </Card> 
            </div>
        )
    } else if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
        return (


            <div>{/*Java*/}
                <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                    <CardTitle style={{ color: '#000', height: '176px', background: 'url(https://www.biernet.nl/images/brouwerij/55296-Bavaria%20logo.jpg) center / cover' }}></CardTitle>

                    <CardText><h4>Bavaria Cashback</h4>
                        <p>Tijdens mijn werkzaamheden bij Acorel Commerce in Alkmaar, heb ik met trots mee mogen werken aan het actieplatform van Bavria. Deze web-app is gebouwd in Java.</p></CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                        <Button colored style={{ width: "100%" }} ><a href="https://cashback.bavaria.com">Website</a></Button>
                    </CardActions>

                </Card></div>
        )
    }
    else if (this.state.activeTab === 2) {
        return (
            <div>{/*Python*/}
                <Card shadow={5} style={{ minWidth: '450', margin: 'auto' }}>
                    <CardTitle style={{ color: '#000', height: '176px', background: 'url(https://indigo.amsterdam/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/python-django-logo-1024x576.jpg) center / cover' }}></CardTitle>

                    <CardText><h4>Foodify</h4>
                        <p>Foodify is een schoolproject gebouwd voor het vak Praktijkvaardigheden 2. Deze applicatie is gebouwd zodat mensen die te veel hebben gekookt en mensen die niet hebben gekookt elkaar tegemoetkomen. Het doel is om voedselverspilling te voorkomen.</p></CardText>
                    <CardActions border>
                        <Button colored style={{ width: "100%" }} ><a href="https://github.com/aminaloui/Foodify-Praktijk-2-">Github</a></Button>
                    </CardActions>

                </Card></div>
        )
    }
    }  

}

export default project;
```

projecten.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Project, {toggleCattegories} from './project';
import { Tabs, Tab, Grid, Cell, Card, CardTitle, CardActions, Button, CardText } from 'react-mdl';


class Projecten extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { activeTab: 0 };
    }
    
  

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="category-tabs">
                <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} onChange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })} ripple>
                    <Tab>Html / Css/ ReactJS</Tab>
                    <Tab>Java</Tab>
                    <Tab>Python / Django</Tab>
                </Tabs>


                <Grid>
                    <Cell col={6} hidePhone="true" hideTablet="true" >
                        <div className="content"> <toggleCattegories/> </div>

                    </Cell>

                </Grid>

                <Grid>
                    <Cell col={2} phone={6} hideDesktop="true" hideTablet="true" >
                        <div className="content">{this.toggleCategoriesMobile()} </div>

                    </Cell>

                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <Cell col={6} tablet={8} hideDesktop="true" hidePhone="true" >
                        <div className="content">{this.toggleCategoriesTablet()} </div>

                    </Cell>

                </Grid>





            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default Projecten;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's because it's "defined but never used" just like the error says. If you don't need it, remove it.

Comment: Point number 2, not relevant to your error message but worth for you knowing: by convention, all react components must start with a capital letter.

Comment: i am using it , i'm trying to render the imported component using <toggleCattegories/>

Comment: You aren't using "project" which is what the error states. It's an unused import, remove it. Do **exactly what the error message tells you to do**.

Comment: i think you don't understand what the problem is in the code. i want to use "project" by rendering an component from "project.js" but it doesn't work.

Comment: The confusion is arising from your code being incomprehensible. What is `toggleCategories`? Right now it is a method on the `project` component, by looking at your code, `toggleCategories` is not a component itself, nor can it be accessed by anything that is not the `project` component. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `Project` correctly.

You have a `toggleCategories` function that should be renamed to `render`. Class components must have a `render` function that returns the JSX.

Once you have renamed the above, you no longer import `{ toggleCategories }`, you only need to `import Project` and where you have `<toggleCategories />`, replace it with `<Project />`

Comment: If i use render instead of the toggleCategories, the constructor doesn't work.

Comment: Apologies for the crappy formatted answer, I'm on my phone :D feel free to upvote and accept if it solved your issue ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help , but If i use render instead of the toggleCategories, the constructor doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean the constructor doesn't work?

Comment: in 'project.js' i have an constructor with a state that sets the activeTab. When i only render the toggleCategories function, the activeTab doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You shouldn't have a toggleCategories function, it should be `render`. It doesn't make sense to me why you have state in Project component because it never gets updated. You only ever seem to update the state of the `Projecten` component. State is specific to a single component, it is not shared between components